# Angular 2 service injection using TypeScript 1.5

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, annotations, angular, typescript1.5

I'm trying to get a very basic, functional structure set up for Angular 2.  It will have only the most basic API elements so that as the framework advances, I can advance my structure.

Currently, I'm at my wit's end as to how to perform the simple act of passing services.  Here is some example source, taken right from the comments of the most recent DefinitelyTyped file:

```
class Greeter {
    greet(name: string) {
        return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
    }
}
@Component({
    selector: 'greet',
    appInjector: [Greeter]
})
@View({
    template: `{{greeter.greet('world')}}!`
})
class HelloWorld {
    greeter: Greeter;
    constructor(greeter: Greeter) {
        this.greeter = greeter;
    }
}
bootstrap(HelloWorld);
```

As you can see, I'm using Typescript 1.5 in this example.

I have tried to inject the `Greeting` service in the Component annotation using `hostInjector`, `injectibles` and `appInjector`.  I've also tried adding it to the second argument of the bootstrap call, as in `bootstrap(HelloWorld, [Greeter])`.

In all cases I get this error message when trying to run it in the browser:

**Error during instantiation of Token(ComponentRef)!. ORIGINAL ERROR: Cannot resolve all parameters for HelloWorld(?). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.**

Of course, if I remove `greeter: Greeter` argument from the constructor, the error in question goes away and is replaced by other, expected errors further down the chain.

Ideas?

**EDIT**

I updated the title of this question to specify that I am using TypeScript 1.5

Comment: Not yet.  The error still happens.  I'm still wondering if it's a type definition problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when using typescript 1.5.0-beta and angular 2.0.0-alpha.28 (not sure if the versions are strictly relevant) with gulp.

You need to tell the typescript compiler to export metadata so the DI injector knows what to do. I did this by adding `emitDecoratorMetadata` and `experimentalDecorators` to my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

After that you can add `appInjector: [Greeter]` to your `@Component` declaration like you've done or to the bootstrap declaration:

```
bootstrap(HelloWorld, [Greeter]);
```

Comment: This looks promising.  As soon as I am able to bend Visual Studio 2015 RC to accept these values, I'll let you know if it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding TS2348. I got the same error. Got rid of ComponentAnnotaion and ViewAnnotation and this helped:

```
import {
  bootstrap,
  Component,
  View
} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

Comment: Thanks, gets rid of the TS2348 error, but produces the same error as identified above.  Are you using Angular 2.0.0-alpha.27?  TypeScript 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

I hope your code will work fine in typescript 1.5 release. Right now, you should use Inject annotation in typescript 1.5.0-beta.

```
import {
  ComponentAnnotation as Component,
  ViewAnnotation as View, bootstrap,
  Inject
} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  hostInjector: [Service]
})
@View({
  template: '{{greeting}} world!'
})
class App {
  constructor(@Inject(Service)service: Service) {
    this.greeting = service.greeting();
    setTimeout(() => this.greeting = 'Howdy,', 1000);
  }
}

class Service {
  greeting() {
    return 'Hello';
  }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Comment: Just FYI for anyone reading this now ... hostInjector and viewInjector are no longer in Angular 2. Their last mention was in the change log for Angular 2 Alpha release 31.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, straight out of the plnkr.co template for injecting a service http://plnkr.co/edit/m5sHWWFmgYPrfsMv0u2r

```
import {
  ComponentAnnotation as Component,
  ViewAnnotation as View, bootstrap
} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  viewInjector: [Service]
})
@View({
  template: '{{greeting}} world!'
})
class App {
  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.greeting = service.greeting();
    setTimeout(() => this.greeting = 'Howdy,', 1000);
  }
}

class Service {
  greeting() {
    return 'Hello';
  }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Comment: What version of Angular 2 is it using?  Could you provide a link for the plnkr?

Comment: added it to the answer

Comment: This does indeed work in plunker, but it does not work as TypeScript 1.5.  One of the first errors I get is **TS2348 Value of type 'typeof ComponentAnnotation' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?**  Could this be a typing problem?  Note that I prepend the file with a `///reference path` that points to the latest DefinitelyTyped angular2.d.ts file.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone reading this now ... hostInjector and viewInjector are no longer in Angular 2. Their last mention was in the change log for Angular 2 Alpha release 31.

Answer (score 0):

More a workaround than a solution, but if you move your service definition to a separate file (greeting.ts), and import it

```
import {Greeting} from 'greeting';
```

then the injector works correctly. This is built using tsc from the command line (taken from the 5 min quickstart on angular.io)

```
tsc --watch -m commonjs -t es5 --emitDecoratorMetadata  app.ts
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, but that solution is not working for me.  I tried it with `appInjector` and `hostInjector` in `@Component` and `viewInjector` in `@View` as well as `bootstrap(HelloWorld, [Greeter])`.  Are you using Angular 2.0.0-alpha.28 and TypeScript 1.5.0-beta?

Also, just to confirm, the service in my example is `Greeter`.  The main bootstrap object is `HelloWorld`.  Is that what you really meant?

Comment: @PeteGardner Verified that my versions are the same as yours, and updated my answer to (hopefully) clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

With angular2.0.0-alpha.32 I accomplished this with

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {MyService} from 'js/services/MyService';

// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    viewInjector: [MyService]
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'templates/my-app.tpl.html',
    directives: [NgFor]
})

class MyComponent {
    mySvc:MyService;

    constructor(mySvc:MyService) {
        this.mySvc = mySvc;
    }

    onInit() {
        this.mySvc.getData();
    }
}   

bootstrap(MyComponent, [MyService]);
```

Comment: Just FYI for anyone reading this now ... hostInjector and viewInjector are no longer in Angular 2. Their last mention was in the change log for Angular 2 Alpha release 31